# Is it possible to specify the correlation between two distributions?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, entropy

For context, say there were two academic exams --morning and afternoon-- conducted. I'm only given the summary statistics -- mean, median, skew and kurtosis for the scores on both exams, so I'm unable to say exactly how many students passed, but I can estimate it by fitting the moments and creating a custom pearson distribution. I can estimate, for example, how many students passed the first and the second exam, as well as giving it a standard deviation to quantify my error.

What I would like to do is to estimate the number of students who pass the course, defined as having the average score of both morning and afternoon exams being over 60%. If the performance of students on both tests are completely independent, I suppose this would be easy - I just generate scores for both tests in the form of two lists, average them, count the number of items over 60%, and repeat, say 10000 times.

If both tests are completely dependent, I suppose I would have to order both lists, because the student scoring the highest on the morning exam should also score the highest on the second. What I'm missing is how I should measure the degree of randomness/interdependence (maybe it has something to do with entropy?) in between, where students who score highly on exam 1 also score highly on exam 2, and if there is a package in R that I can use to specify an arbitrary degree of entropy between two variables.

Comment: This is more of a stats question than a programming question.

Comment: he is asking for an R package based on entropy estimators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A renowned concept for measuring entropy between two distributions is [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence):

> In mathematical statistics, the Kullback–Leibler divergence (also called relative entropy) is a measure of how one probability distribution is different from a second, reference probability distribution.

To make the measure symmetric, you can use [Jensen-Shannon divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) as well.

For the implementation of KL divergence, you can use [this package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/philentropy/versions/0.4.0/topics/KL) in R.

Answer (score 0):

A special case of KL-divergence is [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information), which is a better measure of interdependence which is what you're looking for. Instead of calculating the divergence from a reference distribution, mutual information is basically equal to the KL-divergence between the joint probability and the product of the marginal probability distributions. Mutual information is also equal to the sum of each marginal distribution's entropy minus their joint entropy, meaning that you can estimate the individual and joint entropies first, then sum them together to estimate mutual information.

Here is one implementation of mutual information for R, although there have been many other estimators introduced:

- https://github.com/majianthu/copent